# Cakephp Warning (512)

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

Hello first of all I'm new with cakephp.
I have a site developed with cakephp restored from a backup, it works well but I get the following warnings:

```
Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_spa' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_spa' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_corporac_remanso2_list' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_corporac_remanso2_list' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]
Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_corporac_remanso2_nodes' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]

Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_corporac_remanso2_nodes' to File cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 309]
```

In wampserver it works well, those messages are only when the site is up in the hosting.

Comment: It looks like your cache is misconfigured because PHP does not have write access where it expects to have one. What steps have you taken to troubleshoot?

Comment: Belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: that message is showed at the top of the site: corporacionremanso.com.co I read and I changed the permission of the folder app/tmp to 0777 but this does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not in 2.4.x version, then it is possible that your /tmp structure is missing. Recreate it from /cakephp/app/tmp/ (and then check the permissions). From 2.4 cake will create the missing folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was because there was not enough disk space at the host. I just asked for more space and it was all.